# What is the best way to take backup snowflake tables as in Azure blob?

Tags: python, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement to store all the snowflake tables as Azure blob storage(Parquet).

I have identified two ways,

1.Create a external stage and write a procedure to unload all tables one by one directly to azure blob. (external stage --> Azure Blob).

2.Create a internal stage load the files to internal stage, once files generated prepare a standalone python script in local move the files internal stage to azure blob(Internal stage --> Local --> Azure blob)

Please suggest any other easiest way would help.

Comment: Hi  - can you explain why you want to do this? Is this just to have a backup of your Snowflake tables (because you think Snowflake might fall over)? Or do you need to use these files for some other purpose?

Answer (score 0):

What is the end goal? If the consumers of the Parquet files want to keep everything in sync, it might be time for them to adopt Snowflake's Iceberg Tables:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-iceberg

This will keep your Snowflake tables outside in Azure's blob storage as Parquet files - no need to add another synchronization layer.

The caveat is that anyone that wants to read those Parquet files should use them through the Iceberg catalog, to make sure they are reading the latest version of the table.

If they are using Spark, the change would look something like:

```
spark.read
  .format("parquet")
  .load("file")
```

to

```
spark.read
  .format("iceberg")
  .load("my_catalog.my_table")
```

(Iceberg tables are in Public Preview right now)